# Java Thread.sleep

Tags: java, multithreading

When ever we try Threads.sleep in our code, we have to catch an InterruptedException. This means that the thread was not able to sleep for the time we specified, right? So how can a thread that we put to sleep be interrupted ? Can anyone explain this concept?

Answer (score 2):

How can a thread be interrupted ? I can call [Thread.interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) on it.

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html):

> An interrupt is an indication to a thread that it should stop what it
>   is doing and do something else. It's up to the programmer to decide
>   exactly how a thread responds to an interrupt, but it is very common
>   for the thread to terminate. This is the usage emphasized in this
>   lesson.

It's worth reading [this article from JavaSpecialists](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue056.html) to understand how to handle interrupts cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Concurrency In Practice (Peierls, Bloch, Bowbeer, Holmes, Lea)](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/)

For example, if the application is being shut down while this thread is sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

It might be interrupted by an alarm or another external event.

Comment: What are you talking about? Not Java, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

An InterruptionException occures, if the thread woke up earlier than the given time.

The Execption is only thrown to give you(the thread) an option to handle the special case.

In the most common cases you dont need to catch this execption. I prefer a small helper for that:

```
public class Sleeper {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Sleeper.class);

    /**
     * @param time
     * @param units
     * @return milliseconds 
     */
    public static long sleepUnsafe(final long time, final TimeUnit units) {
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long millis = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(time, units);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            final long timeSlept = end - start;
            final long difference = millis - timeSlept;
            if (difference > 0) {
                Sleeper.log.warn("should sleep for " + time + " " + units + ". But was awaked after " + (end - start) + " ms. Diffence is " + difference
                        + "ms.");
                return difference;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param millis
     * @return
     */
    public static long sleepUnsafe(final long millis) {
        return Sleeper.sleepUnsafe(millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Brian Agnew said, exception in `sleep()` is the reaction to `interrupt()`. The concept here is that a thread should provide ways to stop itself; if it's not sleeping it should check for the interrupt status from time to time via `interrupted()` or `isInterrupted()` and react accordingly. But if thread is sleeping and we want to cancel it's execution, we would be doomed: the thread would be just sleeping, it wouldn't care to look for the `interrupted` flag. But that's what the built-in behavior of `sleep()` is: if the thread is interrupted before sleep finishes, we get an InterruptedException.